# change text in columns

Tags: mysql, rename

i have mysql table 
items
and there is one column called 
item_location 
the values is like this format 
number-number-number

```
'1-22-5',
'6-19-44',
```

and so on ..
how could i let mysql separate each number to new column 
like i need explode the item_location to three columns 
item_location

```
'1-22-5',
'6-19-44',
```

to

```
item_location,item_area,item_row
1,22,5
6,19,44
```

and do thats for all records ..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming you column is named `my_col`  .You could use some  substring_index  for split  the column

```
  select 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '-',1) as item_location
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '-',2), '-' -1) as item_area
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '-',-1) as item_row
  from  my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert in new table by spliting your column data in following way :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (item_location,item_area,item_row)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('your_column', '-', 1), '-', -1),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('your_column', '-', 2), '-', -1),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('your_column', '-', 3), '-', -1) 
FROM single_column_table
```